Google Collab Pro+ Runtime disconnect Issues
I have been running a notebook for the past 3 days for ML purposes, everything has been working as intended. All of a sudden the Runtime disconnects and upon re-connecting the code has stopped executing, this has happened numerous times at this point.
Code is fine as it complete successfully with a smaller dataset, how can I determine what has caused the code to stop executing, give Pro+ also costs money per compute units this has now cost a bit.
All resources were well under 100% utilization and there was plenty of compute units at the time.
